# How to populate an output variable using Execute Immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm porting a stored procedure from Transact-SQL to Oracle and I have the following construct which must use dynamic SQL within a cursor loop:

```
open curRBL
--iterate over cursor rows of interest, and execute a query to evaluate a rule for each row.
fetch next from curRBL into varLimitNumber, varComponentRow, varComponentColumn, varFilterString
while curRBL%FOUND
begin
     --count the matching current sample records
    set varRBLSqlQuery = 'select count(*) into :1 from samples where samplecode= :2  and auditflag=0 and :3 ';

    execute immediate varRBLSqlQuery using varResult, varSampleCode, varFilterString; <--doesn't work as I need

    if varResult>0
    --do something with the current cursor row...
    begin
      --some code goes here
    end;
fetch next from curRBL into varLimitNumber, varComponentRow, varComponentColumn, varFilterString;
end; --cursor loop
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get *count(*)* from the dynamic query into my local variable *varResult* (my lines 5 & 6 above don't work in this respect).  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
varRBLSqlQuery := 'select count(*) from samples where samplecode= :1  and auditflag=0 and :2 ';
execute immediate varRBLSqlQuery into varResult using varSampleCode, varFilterString;
...
```

Comment: Ok, tried that. I get a compiler error "PL/SQL: SQL statement ignored" for this line set varRBLSqlQuery = 'select count(*) from samples where samplecode= :1  and auditflag=0 and :2 ';

Comment: I don't know t-sql, but I suppose that expressions like 'set var = value;'  should be replaced with 'var := value;'

Comment: Ah! I see that now. "Set var =" is Sql Server Tansact-SQL, and I hadn't spotted that.

Comment: It also looks like Execute Immediate has to take a literal string as the argument, not a string variable, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Thanks both for the help. Problem sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
set varRBLSqlQuery = 'select count(*) into varResult from samples where samplecode= :1  and auditflag=0 and :2 ';

execute immediate varRBLSqlQuery using varSampleCode, varFilterString;
```

Try this.. btw what is the final input? You are sending the param but comparing it with what ?